# How to delete and override a file in java?

Tags: java

I want to rename and delete "products2.txt" to "products.txt".
if I test with another files "test1" and "test2", in the same directory, will work fine, but with my filles "products" and "products2", doesn't work, not even to delete the file with `file.delete();`

```
              try{
              File file =  new File("C:\\Users\\J3TyX\\Desktop\\proiect JAVA PENTA\\products.txt"); 
              Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 
              File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\J3TyX\\Desktop\\proiect JAVA PENTA\\products2.txt");
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
              BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
              System.out.println("ID number:");
              int delete = in.nextInt();
              String lineToRemove = Objects.toString(delete,null);
              String currentLine;

              while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                  String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                  String trimmLine[] = trimmedLine.split(" ");
                  String part1 = trimmLine[0];

                  if(!part1.equals(lineToRemove)) {
                      writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                  }
              }

              writer.flush();
              writer.close();
              reader.close();
              sc.close();

              file.delete();
              tempFile.renameTo(file);
           }catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Comment: Is it because the products.txt is being opened by another application which avoids your program to delete it?

Comment: Instead of copying the contents, try [`File#renameTo(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) or, if using NIO, [`Files#move(Path,Path,CopyOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).